# Windows Phone 7 add listbox with itemtemplate and datatemplate from code?

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What is the correct way to add this with source code?

**edited:**

tried this:

```
public static DataTemplate createDataTemplate()
{
    return (DataTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(
        @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
            <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Title}"" />
            <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Description}"" />
            <Image Source=""{Binding Image}"" />
      </DataTemplate>"
      );
}
```

when i call this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                ListBox lb      = new ListBox();
                lb.ItemTemplate = createDataTemplate();
                //...then add to a pivotitem
}
```

i get this:

The property 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Template' is set more than once. [Line: 3 Position: 32]

why?

Comment: (Please use uppercase i's when referring to yourself rather than some variable. Also please start sentences with uppercase letters. Thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply define the shared template in your App.xaml file under the "Resources" element.

Define it in App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySharedTemplate">
    <StackPanel Margin="10" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Access it in code:

```
#region FindResource
/// <summary>Get a template by the type name of the data.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The template type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="initial">The source element.</param>
/// <param name="type">The data type.</param>
/// <returns>The resource as the type, or null.</returns>
private static T FindResource<T>(DependencyObject initial, string key) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject current = initial;

    if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains(key))
    {
        return (T)Application.Current.Resources[key];
    }

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is FrameworkElement)
        {
            if ((current as FrameworkElement).Resources.Contains(key))
            {
                return (T)(current as FrameworkElement).Resources[key];
            }
        }

        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }

    return default(T);
}
#endregion FindResource
```

Use it in your UI:

```
DataTemplate newTemplate = null;
string templateKey = "MySharedTemplate";

try { newTemplate = FindResource<DataTemplate>(this, templateKey); }
catch { newTemplate = null; }

if (newTemplate != null)
{
    this.ListBox1.ItemTemplate = newTemplate;
}
```

Comment: i have a pivot, and a lot of pivotitem on it. every pivotitem has a listbox, thats why i need to add this lines with code. what alternatives can i do? in my xaml file there is not any template at the moment...