# How to custom the ListBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to make a conversation view with ListBox, but I don't know how to start.
Just like WhatsApp Conversation View...

[image]

Thanks~

Comment: I am also looking for the same....Just want to customize ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom `ItemTemplate` for dialog items. Also, if you have some different layouts for incoming, outgoing, voice messages, etc, you may be interesting in [`Implementing DataTemplateSelector`](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ItemTemplate for your listbox using a DataTemplate. However, as you require doing conditional formatting etc you probably want to write an element in C# that you can bind to in your delegate. See [Windows Phone 7 add listbox with itemtemplate and datatemplate from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684305/windows-phone-7-add-listbox-with-itemtemplate-and-datatemplate-from-code)